# How does SQL Server evaluate logical expressions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I am writing a bit complex sql query which - I am afraid - can be heavy to execute. So I'd like to know how MS SQL Server works out some things.

If there is logical expression like ex1 AND ex2, does server always evaluate both of them ? Does it always evaluate ex1 first, and then ex2 (if needed) ?
Is it specified, and can I rely on that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logical operators OR AND in condition and order of conditions in WHERE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5333/logical-operators-or-and-in-condition-and-order-of-conditions-in-where)?

Comment: It’s with `or` and `and` conditions where the evaluation is done in a short-cut way, so as soon as one condition is matched (`or`) or not matched (`and`) the rest of conditions are not evaluated. Because of that, it’s always strongly recommended to place the most common condition in the first place, and then the rest following this rule.

Comment: Does that mean that server always evaluates expressions in the same order I write them ? Can I rely on that ?

Answer (score 3):

What you are referring to is short-cut evaluation.  And, yes, if SQL Server is evaluating the expressions and the first that it evaluates is false, then it does not (necessarily) evaluate the second one.

There are some caveats on this.  First, you have no way to knowing which one SQL Server chooses to evaluate first.  If one is cheap and the other expensive (say a user-defined function), then you can control the execution order using a `case` expression.

Second, the evaluation of expressions is generally *not* what takes time in a query.  Reading the data and matching rows for joins and aggregations are generally the time-consuming parts of the queries.  So focusing on micro-optimizations may not really help you much in gaining performance.

Comment: Good answer @GordonLinoff but I am quite sure than in a `case when` statement the evaluation is always performed in the way you write it. If not so, why `case when 1=1 then 1 when 1=1 and 2=2 then 2 else 3 end` will always return 1?

Comment: @JaimeDrq . . . The OP is referring to boolean expressions, not the `when` clauses in a `case` expression (unless I'm misunderstanding the question).

Comment: Ooops, you are right... I mixed them up my apologizes.

Answer (score -1):

The server evaluate **exp1** first and if it is true then evaluate **exp2**,  and if **exp1** is false then **exp2** not evaluated

Sql 'and' logical operation work this way unlike 'or' operation