# Sql where clause, Get All if value is empty or null else use like statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have a column

-Category

Red
Blue
Yellow

I would like to render a conditional statement. If Title is null, then get all, else title like @Title.

```
  SELECT [Category]
  FROM [dbo].[Records]
  WHERE 
         CASE WHEN @SearchText IS NULL 
                        THEN title = title 
                        ELSE (Title like '%' + @SearchText + '%') 
         END
```

The results should look like this

if @Title is null or empty

return all values

Red
Blue
Yellow

Else where title like '%red%'
return red

This is the best I could ome up with

```
    and (
            (@SearchText IS NULL and title = title)
          or
          (@SearchText IS not NULL and Title like '%' + @SearchText + '%')
        )
```

Comment: I would suggest you use Dynamic SQL to run separate queries depending on the value of `title`. Or youe app can just run two separate queries using an `if` block.

Comment: @TheImpaler I plan on doing this with 8 different columns that's almost 100 different query combinations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a stored procedure that will optionally search columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205526/how-do-i-create-a-stored-procedure-that-will-optionally-search-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can be updated to this:

```
SELECT [Category]
FROM [dbo].[Records]
WHERE (@SearchText IS NULL OR (Title like '%' + ISNULL( @SearchText ,'')+ '%'))
```

If you feed `null` then first condition will be `true` else second.

Comment: Doesn't the or condition run the like statement (Title like '%' + @SearchText + '%') ? I don't want to execute the like statement if i'ts null. The like statment doesn't use indexes and will scan the entire table.

Comment: it will check the first condition and if its true then will not go to next condition, its similar to how you use in any other language

Comment: @KVPrashant: that statement isn't entirely correct - SQL Server **DOES NOT** do boolean evaluation strictly as the statement is written; it is quite possible the `LIKE` will be evaluated first. T-SQL is **NOT** like a "deterministic" programming language like C# - there's **no guarantee** for this behavior

Comment: @marc_s I just gave a thought with out any background search, thanks for correcting. if you don't want to query to check the second statement at all you might try write separate query : if SearchText is null (just select all) else (Select with that like filter)

Comment: What @marc_s is trying to say is that you can't guarantee the order of evaluation, but that does not change the actual results, because ultimately both sides of the `OR` are evaluated. The only time this usually makes a difference is when there is a subquery involved, or in cases of exceptions such as overflow.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT [Category]
FROM [dbo].[Records]
WHERE ISNULL(@SearchText, '') = '' OR Title like '%' + @SearchText + '%'
```

but I think

```
SELECT [Category]
FROM [dbo].[Records]
WHERE Title like CONCAT('%', @SearchText, '%')
```

probably works.

See also [How does SQL Server evaluate logical expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56675622/how-does-sql-server-evaluate-logical-expressions) in order to understand logic operator evaluation in sql server.